# Static File Serving with Extensionless MVC3 on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have a MVC3 site in .Net 4.0 running on IIS6 with extensionless manner successfully.

One function og the site is the generate static files for user to download. One type of file is CSV, I generated files on server which is accessible via http://DevServer:1234/StaticFile/1.csv which works fine.

However the requirement is changed, client wants file extension to be ".rpt" instead of ".csv" and all the content of file leaves the same. The code has been adjusted accordingly, I have verified the new file is generated properly at correct path. But when I tried to load it via http://DevServer:1234/StaticFile/1.rpt web server returns 404 error code. If I simply rename the file extension back to CSV on server I have no problem loading it.

Sounds like IIS6 is not able to server tthe request properly.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: To get your site working, did you setup MVC as a Wild Card mapping in IIS?

Comment: No i did not setup wildcard mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a custom MIME type to IIS to tell it to serve up .rpt files.

- Open up your **IIS management console** and find the site you want this to work with.
- Right click on your site and choose properties and choose the "**HTTP Headers**" tab
- Press the "mime types" button
- In the dialog, under extension type "**.rpt**" (without the quotes) and under mime type: type "**text/csv**" (without the quotes)

Comment: It works for me. But what does MIME to do with MVC3 project here?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You noted that you're outputting these static files to the disk. IIS will only serve up known MIME types. Does this answer your question?